# Understanding the Glassfish console JNDI output

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish, jndi, ejb-3.0

When I deploy my EJB Module (containing a session bean); I see the output below in the Glassfish Console (in Netbeans):

```
Info:   EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB NewSessionBean: [java:global/EJBModule1/NewSessionBean!com.Hello.NewSessionBeanRemote, java:global/EJBModule1/NewSessionBean]
Info:   EJB5182:Glassfish-specific (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB NewSessionBean: [com.Hello.NewSessionBeanRemote, com.Hello.NewSessionBeanRemote#com.Hello.NewSessionBeanRemote]
```

I have two questions:

```
1) Why does the remote interface have a JNDI reference? I thought it was just the EJB.
2) Why is there a comma, which appears to separate two JNDI references per line?
```

Answer (score 4):

> 1) Why does the remote interface have a JNDI reference? I thought it
>   was just the EJB.

It's not the RemoteInterface which has an JNDI reference, its just a portable JNDI reference which includes the name of interface which is implemented.

See the following explanation from [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/MaheshKannan/entry/portable_global_jndi_names):

> Client applications need to use global JNDI name to lookup an EJB. All
>   along the ejb specifications had been silent about portability of such
>   global jndi names. This allowed each vendor to assign a global jndi
>   names to EJBs in a vendor specific way. This meant that the client
>   code that performed a lookup using global JNDI names were inherently
>   non portable across appserver vendor implementations.
>
> EJB 3.1 solves the above problem by mandating that every container
>   must assign (at least one) well defined global JNDI names to EJBs. The
>   general syntax of a (portable) global JNDI name of an EJB is of the
>   form:
>
> **`java:global/[<application-name>]/<module-name>/<bean-name>!<fully-qualified-bean-interface-name>`**
>
> In addition to the above name, if the EJB exposes just a single client
>   view (that is it implements just one interface or the no interface
>   view), the container is also mandated to map the bean to
>
> **`java:global/[<application-name>]/<module-name>/<bean-name>`**
>
> Where
>
> 1. `<application-name>` defaults to the bundle name (.ear file name) without the bundle extension. This can be overridden in
>      application.xml. Also,  is applicable only if the
>      bean is packaged inside a .ear file.
> 2. `<module-name>` defaults to bundle name (.war or .jar) without the bundle extension. Again, this can be overridden in ejb-jar.xml.
> 3. `<bean-name>` defaults to the unqualified class name of the bean. However, if `@Stateful` or `@Stateless` or `@Singleton` uses the name
>      attribute, then the value specified there will be used as the bean
>      name.

And

> 2) Why is there a comma, which appears to separate two JNDI references
>   per line?

Because commas are used to separate entries in a list :) The answer to Question 1 should also answer this one, there is one entry which contains only the bean name and one entry which contains bean name + interface name.

Comment: Thanks +1 for the link.  Are you able to look at my other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40045883/windows-client-and-linux-ubuntu-server ?