# Windows Client and Linux (Ubuntu) server

Tags: java, ubuntu, jakarta-ee, glassfish-4

**Update**
The problem appears to be related to the fact that the Ubuntu Operating System is virtualized i.e. I have used Vmware Workstation to create a host Operating system (Windows) and a guest operating system (Ubuntu).

When I deploy the EJB to Glassfish on the host (Windows); I can lookup the EJB using a servlet client on either the host (Windows) or the guest (Ubuntu).  I can also specify the settings for either the host or the guest to find the EJB.  I believe this is what the issue is i.e. the lookup is always done on the host regardless of whether the host settings or guest settings are supplied in the servlet.  Does anyone have a similar experience and what did you do to resolve it.

**Original Question**

Please see the code below:

```
Properties props = new Properties();  
        props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial",
            "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
        props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs",
            "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
        props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.state",
            "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");
        props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "192.168.163.128");
        props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
        try
        {
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
        RemoteInterfaceRemote r = (RemoteInterfaceRemote) ctx.lookup("java:global/Course/RemoteInterface!com.w0051977.dao.RemoteInterfaceRemote");//!com.w0051977.dao.RemoteInterfaceRemote
        String greeting = r.Greeting("Ian");
        System.out.println("got here");
        } catch (NamingException n)
        {
           System.out.println(n.toString());
    }
```

The code is found inside a Servlet and works as expected i.g. the greeting variable contains: "Good Afternoon Ian".  The Servlet runs on a Windows PC and connects to a Windows server were the enterprise bean is hosted.

However, when I move the bean to a Linux (Ubuntu) PC I have problems.  The code above will run inside a Servlet on the Linux PC (the client and server are on the same pc in this case).  However, I cannot get the code above to work inside a servlet on a Windows PC.

Is there anything special you have to do when a windows client (servlet) connects to a Linux (Ubuntu) server? I obviously change the IP address in the code above when moving server.  The exception is:

```
Lookup failed for 'java:global/Course/RemoteInterface' in SerialContext[myEnv={org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=3700, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory, org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=ubuntu, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming
```

The output from the Glassfish console (on Ubuntu) is:

```
[2016-10-14T08:57:16.824-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=96 _ThreadName=admin-listener(7)] [timeMillis: 1476460636824] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]
[2016-10-14T08:57:16.890-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=96 _ThreadName=admin-listener(7)] [timeMillis: 1476460636890] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]
[2016-10-14T08:57:17.238-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-EJB-00054] [javax.enterprise.ejb.container] [tid: _ThreadID=96 _ThreadName=admin-listener(7)] [timeMillis: 1476460637238] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Portable JNDI names for EJB RemoteInterface: [java:global/Course/RemoteInterface, java:global/Course/RemoteInterface!com.w0051977.dao.RemoteInterfaceRemote]]]
[2016-10-14T08:57:17.248-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-EJB-00055] [javax.enterprise.ejb.container] [tid: _ThreadID=96 _ThreadName=admin-listener(7)] [timeMillis: 1476460637248] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Glassfish-specific (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB RemoteInterface: [com.w0051977.dao.RemoteInterfaceRemote#com.w0051977.dao.RemoteInterfaceRemote, com.w0051977.dao.RemoteInterfaceRemote]]]
[2016-10-14T08:57:17.432-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [WARN] [] [org.jboss.weld.Event] [tid: _ThreadID=96 _ThreadName=admin-listener(7)] [timeMillis: 1476460637432] [levelValue: 900] [[
  WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.]]
[2016-10-14T08:57:17.472-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [WARN] [] [org.jboss.weld.Event] [tid: _ThreadID=96 _ThreadName=admin-listener(7)] [timeMillis: 1476460637472] [levelValue: 900] [[
  WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.]]
[2016-10-14T08:57:17.482-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [WARN] [] [org.jboss.weld.Event] [tid: _ThreadID=96 _ThreadName=admin-listener(7)] [timeMillis: 1476460637482] [levelValue: 900] [[
  WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.]]
[2016-10-14T08:57:18.078-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=96 _ThreadName=admin-listener(7)] [timeMillis: 1476460638078] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Course was successfully deployed in 1,282 milliseconds.]]
```

I have spent days looking into this.  Please help.

The output of: sudo lsof -i:3700 is (note that I have noe changed the IP version to 4 as per @RCs comment:

[image]

There is a reply when Pinging the Ubuntu PC from the Windows PC.

Here is the JNDI tree on the Linux server:

[image]

What should the JNDI lookup name be on the remote server? Do I have to do any configuration on the local Glassfish PC (Windows PC)?

Comment: Can I provide more information to encourage a reply? I have spent days Googling and trying many many different things.

Comment: Can you post the output of `sudo lsof -i:3700` (run from the ubuntu box) and the output of `ping ubuntu` run from the Windows box?

Comment: @RC, I have posted the output to the original post.  Thanks.

Comment: The Ubuntu PC is a virtualized (VMWARE) PC.  The host of the virtualised PC is the Windows PC.

Comment: OK, according to the lsof output, java is listening on IPV**6** not IPV**4** and you are using ipv4 on the client side, that's probably the issue here

Comment: @RC, I guess I have to options I.e. Configure Linux to be IP v4 or configure windows to be ipV6.  Which would you do? Also surely if it was down to this then there would be a communication exception?

Comment: For question 1, as you like, for question 2, I don't know

Comment: @RC, I ran this command in Linux: sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1.  Then ran: sudo lsof -i:3700 which now says IPV4.  No difference.  Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: No, sorry maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829922/how-to-access-ejb-on-remote-server

Comment: Is there anything I can do to debug this? I am completely stuck.

Comment: Are there any logs anywhere I can perhaps use? The Server.log on the client is empty.  The server.log on the server is empty.  What can I do?

Comment: I have switched server roles.  Ubuntu is now the client and Windows is the server.  It works that way around.  I am wandering if it is something firewall related on the Ubuntu machine.

Comment: @RC, I have got somewhere.  Could you read my update?

Answer (score 0):

It does sound like it might possibly be a firewall issue. Try telnet your Linux machine from the windows machine on port 3700. If that fails to connect, add firewall rules to allow incoming traffic on port 3700. This should allow for the EJB communication. But you might also want to allow your http / https incoming requests as well.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I believe that Ubuntu does not gave a firewall.  I believe this is a virtualisation issue rather than a firewall issue.