# Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-ws, netbeans-7

I am a .NET Developer learning Java.  Please see the code below:

The class `HelloWorld`

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("generic")
public class HelloWorld {
    @Context
    private UriInfo context;
    public HelloWorld() {
    }
    @GET
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public String getHtml() {
        return "<?xml version='1.0'?><PARTS><TITLE>Computer Parts</TITLE><PART><ITEM>Motherboard</ITEM></PART></PARTS>";
    }
}
```

The class `JavaApplication3`

```
package javaapplication3;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import sun.misc.IOUtils;

/**
 *
 * @author 3212627
 */
public class JavaApplication3 {
    private static String charset;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, JAXBException {
        //Get the URI by selecting the RESTful web services folder under the web app project.   Then right click on the underlying node
        //and select: TestResourceURI
        String content;
        String uri ="http://localhost:8080/HelloRestService/webresources/generic";
        URL url = new URL(uri);
        HttpURLConnection connection =  (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        //connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(String.class); //I changed Customer.class to String.class

        InputStream xml = connection.getInputStream();
        String str = (String) jc.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(xml); //line causing exception
        connection.disconnect();       
    }

}
```

The exception returned is:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"PARTS"). Expected elements are (none)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:726)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:247)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:242)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:109)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1131)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:556)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:538)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:153)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:380)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:619)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3129)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:880)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:118)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:504)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:243)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:204)
    at javaapplication3.JavaApplication3.main(JavaApplication3.java:46)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)
```

I have marked the line that causes the exception.  What is the problem?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? get the result as `String` or as java bean?

Comment: which version of Java EE do you use 6 or 7?

Comment: @Nicolas Filotto, both.  Two calls.  The first should return an XML String and the second a Java Bean.

Answer (score 2):

The main purpose of `JAXB` is to do the mapping between `XML` and a `Java Bean` but to be able to do it, it relies on annotations from `javax.xml.bind.annotation` that you need to declare on the fields or on the getters of your target Java Bean.

So for example here, your mapping could be defined as next:

The class `Parts`

```
public class Parts {
    @XmlElement(name = "TITLE")
    private String title;
    @XmlElement(name = "PART")
    private List<Part> parts;

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public void setTitle(final String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public List<Part> getParts() {
        return this.parts;
    }

    public void setParts(final List<Part> parts) {
        this.parts = parts;
    }
}
```

The class `Part`

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Part {
    @XmlElement(name = "ITEM")
    private String item;

    public String getItem() {
        return this.item;
    }

    public void setItem(final String item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
}
```

Once you have your mapping defined, you need to provide it to your `JAXBContext` to be able to `unmarshal` your `XML` content to get an instance of the class `Parts`:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Parts.class); 

InputStream xml = connection.getInputStream();
Parts parts = (Parts) jc.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(xml);
```

Here is [a good tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JAXB/article.html) about `JAXB` that you should read. You should also read [the one from oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/index.html).